# Double-clicking on file opens wrong executable

Tags: windows

For several reasons, my Windows users have several versions of an executable file in folders scattered around their computers. Because they are not technically versed, they have opened the wrong version of the executable and loaded in files with that wrong version.

This has caused different versions of the executable to be associated with the file extension. So when they double-click, the wrong executable runs.

I can fix this by going on to their machines and using Open With to locate the correct version of the executable. Or I can delete all wrong versions of the executable (if I can find them), forcing them to browse to the correct one.

Is there an easier way of associating a file extension with a specified executable in a specified location? Preferably with a batch file, but failing that I'll take a registry entry.

Comment: This on a domain?  And what versions of Windows are in play here?

Comment: You can use Group Policy Preferences to create file associations, but maybe the better solution would be to get rid of the wrong versions altogether.

Comment: I agree. Get rid of the old versions, and then perhaps also create the group policy preferences (protecting against a user installing the wrong version again).

Comment: Some of my users are working from home, and not on a domain. So I can't use group policy.

Comment: They use Windows Vista, 7 and 8.